# ASP.NET 5, MVC6, WebAPI -> ModelState.IsValid always returns true

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I've seen a lot of posts about IsValid always being true but none of them have helped me solve this problem.  I'm also seeing this problem in ASP.NET 4 using MVC5.  So clearly I'm missing a step somewhere.

Controller method:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]ValuesObject value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(value);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(ModelState);
    }
}
```

ValuesObject Class:

```
public class ValuesObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Name;

    [Range(10, 100, ErrorMessage = "This isn't right")]
    public int Age;
}
```

Body of the POST:

```
{
  Age: 1
}
```

ModelState.IsValid is true.

But I would expect both the Required and Range validations to fail.

What am I missing??

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use fields in your model. it's [one of general conditions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) for your validation.

> In ASP.NET Web API, you can use attributes from the
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace to set validation
>   rules for **properties** on your model.

Replace it with properties and all will work fine:

```
public class ValuesObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(10, 100, ErrorMessage = "This isn't right")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra pair of eyes seeing that!

Comment: I did this, but the ModelState.IsValid never kicks in. The request only returns the Data annotations messages, but not my custom return after checking for errors in the ModelState