# MaxLength does not work, ModelState.IsValid always true - (ASP.MVC 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a method that have `[FromBody]` parameter but it `ModelState.IsValid` keep returning `true` if values are longer than they limited with `MaxLength` attributes in the mapped object.

```
public class AddUserMsg
{
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string name;
}

[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult AddUser([FromBody] AddUserMsg msg)
{
    // Always true even if the name is longer than 10 symbols
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
}
```

I thought it suppose to validate posted data. Any ideas why it does not?

Answer (score 4):

```
public string name;
```

Property should be used instead of field.

```
public string Name { get; set };
```

[ASP.NET 5, MVC6, WebAPI -> ModelState.IsValid always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584294/asp-net-5-mvc6-webapi-modelstate-isvalid-always-returns-true)

Comment: Thank you. Switching to properties fixed the issue.

Comment: Same for VB.NET need to use "Property" statement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [StringLengthAttribute](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation.html#adding-validation-rules-to-the-movie-model). The StringLength is used for ViewModel validation. From docs:

> The StringLength attribute lets you set the maximum length of a string
>   property, and optionally its minimum length.

[MaxLengthAttribute](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/max-length.html#maximum-length) is used by Entity Framework to provide a hint to the dataprovider about the appropriate data type to use for a given property. As you can see from docs:

> Entity Framework does not do any validation of maximum length before
>   passing data to the provider. It is up to the provider or data store
>   to validate if appropriate. For example, when targeting SQL Server,
>   exceeding the maximum length will result in an exception as the data
>   type of the underlying column will not allow excess data to be stored.

Comment: However, `MaxLength` is partly supported by MVC. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21696595/5112433 In OP case it would work for a property.